# While True and condition statements

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to get the answer `m = [0, 2, 0, 4, 0]`:

```
m = []
while True:
    for x in range(1, 6):
        if x == 2:
            m.append(x)
            continue
        else:
            m.append(0)
            continue
        if x == 4:
            m.append(x)
            continue
        else:
            m.append(0)
            continue
    break

print(m)
```

Answer is coming `m = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: You might consider using something like [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to visualize the execution of this program.

Comment: What is the point of the `while` loop?

Comment: You need `elif` here.  `if x == 2:` / `elif x == 4:` / `else:`.  Your code will never get past the first if statement.

Comment: True, and they shouldn't.  He could also solve the problem be deleting the first `else:` clause entirely, but the right answer is `if/elif/else` with no `continue`s.

Comment: IF x == 2 do something and continue ELSE do something else and continue - the later if x==4 is never executed because your code "continues" back to the while loop. There is no need for continues if you fix to if/elif/else

Answer (score 5):

Main issue is you need to use `elif`. You also don't need the while loop.

```
m = []
for x in range(1, 6):
    if x == 2:
        m.append(x)
    elif x == 4:
        m.append(x)
    else:
        m.append(0)

print(m)
```

But this really seems like all you need to do is check if the value is divisible by 2:

```
m = []
for x in range(1, 6):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        m.append(x)
    else:
        m.append(0)

print(m)
```

With a list comprehension:

```
print([x if x % 2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(1, 6)])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` statements are interfering with your conditions.  You should either use them without the else or only use if/elif/else:

```
if x == 2:
   m.append(x)
   continue
if x == 4:
   m.append(x)
   continue
m.append(0)
```

OR

```
if x == 2:
   m.append(x)
elif x == 4:
   m.append(x)
else:
   m.append(0)
```

and, given that you are doing the same thing when x is 2 as when x is 4, you can use an or relation to minimize code duplication:

```
if x == 2 or x == 4:
   m.append(x)
else:
   m.append(0)
```